# Parse.com - Synchronise findInBackground within for loop

Tags: android, json, parse-platform

I wasn't sure how to frame the question title, but, here is what i am trying to do.

**Using Parse.com**

I have a table - Surveys and it has a column with Array datatype. I have a JSONArray stored in this column. The JSONArray has 3 JSONObjects. I have to loop through the 3 JSONObjects, get a field with key "type" and use the value (for example "type_dob") of this key, to query a separate table again. I need this to be done in a row, for example once the result for first key is retrieved, then i have to perform the query for second key.

How can i achieve this?

Sample JSON: `Questions: [{"type":"type_dob","id":"I27y16N5gX"},{"type":"type_text","id":"jGAujtNNZc"},{"type":"type_radio","id":"cCDlrrJYKI"}]`

My present code:

```
public void getDataFromServer() {

    ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

    if (user != null) {

        showProgressDialog("Getting Survey details...");

        int survey_count = user.getInt(Const.Parse_User.SURVEY_COUNT);
        Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "Survey Count: " + survey_count);

        String current_survey = "survey_" + (survey_count + 1);
        Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "Current Survey: " + current_survey);


        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Surveys");
        query.whereEqualTo(Const.Parse_SURVEYS.SURVEY_ID, current_survey);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {

                dismissProgressDialog();

                if (e != null) {
                    Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "Exception while getting data from Parse - Surveys table");
                } else {

                    if (list.size() > 0) {

                        ParseObject object = list.get(0);

                        try {

                            String questions_array = object.getJSONArray(Const.Parse_SURVEYS.QUESTIONS).toString();
                            Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "Questions: " + questions_array);

                            JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray(Const.Parse_SURVEYS.QUESTIONS);

                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);

                                String type = jsonObject.get("type").toString();

//I should write the query for getting data from table matching the String type. //If i do a findInBackground query for each of the key, then its done in a background thread 
//and the for loop exists even before the result for first key comes back. 
//How can i handle this?

                            }


                        } catch (Exception e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need anything else?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are moving slightly in a unfortunate direction with your db design.

As far as I can tell from you question, the better approach for you would be to store an Array of pointers. For instance, having a data class in Parse.com called 'Question', which stores a type and whatever other properties you need.

Now assume you have an Array instead in your 'Surveys' class. Then your code gets rather simple:

```
   ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Surveys");
   query.whereEqualTo(Const.Parse_SURVEYS.SURVEY_ID, current_survey);
   query.include(Const.Parse_SURVEYS.QUESTIONS); // <- IMPORTANT
   query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            ParseObject object = list.get(0);
            // get all Question objects
            List<ParseObject> array = object.getList(Const.Parse_SURVEYS.QUESTIONS);
            // no need to fetch, the data is here
            for (ParseObject question: array) {
                String type = question.getString("type");
                String question = question.getString("question");
                List<String> answerOptions = question.getList("options")
                ...
            }
        }
   }
```

If for some reason you cannot transition to this design, then I believe you want to look into Bolts https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android. With this you get the same async abilities as Promises does in javascript. This means that you can que up a range of background jobs and return only when all are completed.

Though Bolts will aid you, it will not avoid exiting your for-loop before it has completed. This is however just a matter of design, meaning that as long as you are aware of the flow of our program, you can design it accordingly. For instance delaying the dismiss of a progress dialog until all background tasks has completed (or failed).

I however suggest that you look into the documentation about the `query.include()` capabilities together with pointer arrays.

Answer (score 0):

i fetched data like this way from data parse table.

```
 ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Surveys");
           query.whereEqualTo(Const.Parse_SURVEYS.SURVEY_ID, current_survey);
           query.include(Const.Parse_SURVEYS.QUESTIONS); // <- IMPORTANT
           query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                    ParseObject object = list.get(0);
                    // first initilization Jsonobject Array list.
                    List<JSONObject> jsobj = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

                    jsobj  = object.getList(Const.Parse_SURVEYS.QUESTIONS);
                    // no need to fetch, the data is here
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsobj.size(); i++) {
                        Log.e("in the For loop ", ": : ::111111 : " +      jsobj.get(i));
                        JSONObject arr1 = new JSONObject((Map)      jsobj.get(i)); // jsobj.get(i);
                        Log.e("in the For loop ", ": : ::111111 : " + arr1);
                        try {
                            Log.e("in the For loop ",
                                    ": : ::111111 : " +      arr1.getString("name"));
 //                             hear u want to store data in Custom Array      list.
 //                             other wise u store in single String value
                            String type = arr1.getString("type");
                            String question = arr1.getString("question");
                            String options = arr1.getString("options");
 //                             this is my custom getter setter class
                            GetIngredients ai = new GetIngredients();
                            ai.setName(arr1.getString("type"));
                            ai.setQty(arr1.getString("question"));
                            ai.setUnit(arr1.getString("options"))     ;
 //                             this is my custom array
                            arr_Ingredients.add(ai);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Log.e("in the For loop ", ": : :: : " +      jsobj.get(i));
                    }
           }
```

in my parse data base column type is "Array".

Comment: Did you just copy the code from my answer and added a subclass called `GetIngredients` in a code that obviously is about surveys?! WTF?! :D